# VBA: Generating data totals in a dynamically changing Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

In a spreadsheet that has raw data generated from a .CSV file, I end up with 5 columns of data. There could be 300 rows or 354. It always changes. I can't come up with a way to (in a macro):
A) calculate how many rows of data are in the spreadsheet. (Use that number for calculating medians and averages)
B) Select each column and automatically calculate the median number.

[sample of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4u6x.jpg)

Comment: If it is a CSV in Excel, `Activesheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count`

Comment: Plugged that formula into my macro to see what it would do, if anything and it threw an error. I am looking for it to automatically enter a number in a cell somewhere on my spreadsheet that tells how many records (rows) are in the spreadsheet. Then I need to grab those rows in one of the columns.

Comment: You did ask for VBA right (for part A)? Or are you just looking at basic Excel formula something like `=COUNTA(A:A)`? There are many ways to determine the last row.

Comment: Yes, please. VBA for both parts a and b. I am trying to speed up with the macro what will be a very painstaking process on a weekly basis. My VBA knowledge was last put to use in 2014.. If you don't use it, you lose it..

Answer (score 0):

Your part A (using column G on active sheet as example), replace `ActiveSheet` with `Worksheets("Your worksheet name")`

```
Dim lRows As Long, lLastRow As Long

lLastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count,"G").End(xlUp).Row
lRows = lLastRow - 1 ' Less the header row
```

Part B will be your task, some hint here.

```
Dim lLastCol As Long
lLastCol = ActiveSheet.Cells(1,Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer my query here. I haven't had any luck with that code though. As I mentioned, " I am looking for it to automatically ENTER A NUMBER IN A CELL  somewhere on my spreadsheet that tells how many records (rows) are in the spreadsheet."

Comment: Okay, I solved that with an ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = lRows statement.